ModuleNotFoundError while importing moviepy.editor
I'm trying to work with VideoFileClip and vfx functions from the Moviepy library but my interpreter keeps throwing a 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moviepy.editor''.
I've installed and reinstalled Moviepy several times but to no avail
Tried: from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, vfx
Expected: import statement to work
Edit:

Other imports like 'from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip' seem to work except the moviepy.editor

library imageio and the program ffmpeg have already been successfully downloaded so the replies from this post aren't helping T~T



This question is similar to: Can't import moviepy.editor. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=moviepy.editor+no+module+named

Does this help from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip?

@Christoph Rackwitz I've edited my question!

How did you install Moviepy; what command(s) did you use? And is there any chance you have multiple Python installations (e.g., an old one and a new one)? Can you import moviepy by itself? If so, what does print(moviepy) show you? What version of moviepy do you have installed? What version of Python? What OS are you using?
